# How can I use jQuery in CatberryJS application?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to use jQuery in my web application on [CatberryJS framework](http://catberry.org/). How can I do it?

Comment: Although it isn't grounds for closing your question, a total lack of effort on your part will make it pretty improbably that you will get a high quality answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using jQuery library registered globally

You can use jQuery as usual, just include this script tag into your "head" component:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

And then feel free to use jQuery functions in any component's code except its constructor and the "[render](http://catberry.org/documentation#cat-component-interface)" method.

## Using jQuery as a part of built `bundle.js`

In this case you can install jQuery using npm like this:

```
npm install jquery --save
```

Then register jQuery as a [Catberry Service](http://catberry.org/documentation#registration-of-own-services) in `./browser.js`

```
var catberry = require('catberry'),
    cat = catberry.create({/* config */}),
    jQuery = require('jquery');

cat.locator.registerInstance('jquery', jQuery);
```

After the jQuery was registered, you can use it in your components resolving it from a [Catberry Service Locator](http://catberry.org/documentation#service-locator):

```
var $ = this.$context.locator.resolve('jquery');
$('.class').html('<div>Hello, World!</div>');
```

## Additionally

If you would like to use jQuery functions in component's constructor or component's "[render](http://catberry.org/documentation#cat-component-interface)" method you should check the environment flag like this:

```
if (this.$context.isBrowser) {
  // crazy jQuery stuff
}
```

Also, keep in mind that to **avoid memory leaks your component should unsubscribe all jQuery events and free all resources used by jQuery functions** in "[unbind](http://catberry.org/documentation#cat-component-interface)" method.

You can use any browser-side library inside component like it's described above for jQuery.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such detailed answer!